# Why do all the fonts look way sharper in Chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, safari, typography

Didn't find any answer to this question on Google, sorry if this has already been asked. I'm currently working on a web project and I noticed that fonts look way bolder in Firefox or Safari compared to Google Chrome (see the linked screenshot, left to right: Chrome, Firefox & Safari).

Why exactly is that? Does Chrome have a different rendering technique?

Thanks for your answers.

EDIT: Sorry, forgot the screenshot. Here it is: [image]

Comment: *"the linked screenshot"* ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it before submitting the post. Fixed now :)

Comment: Maybe it's my eyes, but I can't really tell the diference between Chrome and FF... But Safari seems to have a lower brightness.

Comment: Well yeah maybe I'm the only one to notice this haha. I'm really convinced that FF and Safari's font rendering is bolder, but anyway, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: No you arn't the only one, chrome is indeed slightly sharper then FF on it's font.

Comment: I notice more difference going OS to OS than I do browser to browser. [there are multiple discussions on the topic for Chrome at least](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-webkit/Q13Tg8anOEU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different browsers, different engines, different rendering of the fonts.
The fonts are still pretty similar and you can barely make a difference, but if it become a problem for some of your text or a specific font there is a workaround to it.

Use an image of the text instead of the text itself.

Comment: Not a problem at all, just wanted to know if it was my eyes or if it was "real". Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Gotta love how people downvote without giving a reason to why they do so. If there is anything to change in my answer I'd love to know. >.>

Comment: Got -2 on my question too. And I absolutely don't know why too.

Comment: Maybe because people consider the question opinion-based... which is false since it is a perfectly legit question that has nothing to do with opinions. Why the hell would they even consider this question "opinion-based"? There is a reason why browsers render fonts differently which is what my answer cover. Gotta hate SO community sometimes... Guess I'll stick with comments instead of trying to provide intelligent and researched answers.